# Temp table has only one row inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

Hi I have an SP in which i create a temporary table to store some values.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test] 
  @id int,
  @funds_limit money
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DECLARE @threshold money;

      CREATE TABLE #ConfigurationTemp 
                    (id int, 
                     name varchar(100) not null,
                     type varchar(100),
                     value varchar(100))

      INSERT #ConfigurationTemp EXEC get_config @id, 'testType', null

      select @threshold = value 
      from #ConfigurationTemp 
      where id=@id and name='testLimit'
      print @threshold

      IF (@funds_limit IS NOT NULL) AND (@threshold < @funds_limit)
      BEGIN
         DROP TABLE #ConfigurationTemp;
         RETURN 1000;
      END

      select @threshold = value 
      from #ConfigurationTemp 
      where id=@id and name='testLimit1'
      print @threshold

      IF (@funds_limit IS NOT NULL) AND (@threshold < @funds_limit)
      BEGIN
           DROP TABLE #ConfigurationTemp;
           RETURN 1001;
      END    
    END        
    RETURN 0;
END
```

The temporary table have multiple rows. 
eg:

```
1, fund_limit, testType, 10
2, fund_min_limit, testType, 20
```

I need to first validate the value for **fund_limit** (10) with the user input value (which will be an input parameter to the SP). If the validation fails, i return with an error code. If not, I go for the next check. i.e., **fund_min_limit**. I do the same with it and return a different error code. If no validation fails, i will return 0 which is considered to be a success.

In this case, I am getting same value for threshold always. i.e., the value of first row... 10.

How can I get the different threshold value from the temp table with respect to the name?

Comment: Side note: Temporary tables are automatically dropped upon exiting a stored procedure that created them. There's no need to manually `DROP TABLE` for it.

Comment: Also, how do you know that it only contains one row? It could *easily* contain multiple rows but your `SELECT @scalarvariable = columnvalue` statements will, obviously, only end up assigning the variable with one possible value from one row.

Comment: I can only guess, but I'd say the `@id` parameter you're passing to your `get_config` stored procedure could be the problem...?

Comment: Hi Damien, I tried assigning threshold to a different value. But the second threshold1 did not have any value. So I assumed there was only a single row in the temp table.

Comment: You are processing this table as there is only one row. Did you try `select * from #ConfigurationTemp`? does it return one row?

Comment: Hi Serif, i didnt get you. When i do the select for the first time, it will return the first row value. in the next select statement, shouldnt it return the second row as well? could you please guide me? I am new to SQL

Comment: select * from #ConfigurationTemp returned multiple rows. So is it the select query I am doing wrongly? Can you suggest how I can do it otherwise?

Comment: Put sample data and desired result in your question. Your if-print-return algorithm is not clear for multiple rows case.

Comment: Hey! How can u hope more than 1 row??
In all de SP there is only one simple insert:
INSERT #ConfigurationTemp EXEC get_config @id, 'testType', null

Where u expect to insert more rows???

Comment: get_config sp will return a result set with multiple rows. when i do a select * over the temp table, i can see the multiple rows also.

Comment: @SreeshadP.S. you may process thresholds with a cursor and this will allow you to have unlimited number of rows in # table. If you want to check only specific rows/names - you are doing right only some testing and updates needed. I'll put an answer for this case (specific names check).

Answer (score 1):

When you assign scalar variable with `select` - it may be not assigned (unchanged - may keep value from previous assignment) if this select returned zero rows. To ensure your variable changed it's value rewrite it as `set` expression.

So if you misspelled second threshold name you may be "getting" same @threshold value because second statement does not assign anything to your variable i.e. variable contains value from prior assignment (select). You may test it with additional variable for second threshold - it will be always NULL if i guessed the issue reason.

Also you are applying same `@id` filter which is a scalar variable. But your rows have different ids. So there is no chances right now to get any other threshold's value than for @id given.

```
  set @threshold = (select t.value 
    from #ConfigurationTemp t
    where t.name='testLimit')
  print @threshold

  IF @threshold < @funds_limit
     RETURN 1000;

  set @threshold = (select t.value 
    from #ConfigurationTemp t
    where t.name='testLimit 2')
  print @threshold

  IF @threshold < @funds_limit
       RETURN 1001;
```

`If` will succeed only when both arguments are NOT NULL.

One more approach:

```
declare
  @threshold_a int,
  @threshold_b int,
  @threshold_c int

;with test as
(
  select 'a' as name, 25 as value
  union all
  select 'b', 3
  union all
  select 'c', 100
  union all
  select 'd', -1
)
select
  @threshold_a = case when t.name = 'a' then t.value else @threshold_a end,
  @threshold_b = case when t.name = 'b' then t.value else @threshold_b end,
  @threshold_c = case when t.name = 'c' then t.value else @threshold_c end
from test t

select
  @threshold_a as [a],
  @threshold_b as [b],
  @threshold_c as [c]

GO
```

single select, several variables.

Comment: I have the same issue. In my case there are 4 rows in the temp table for the same id and type. But the name is different. I want to get the threshold value for these 4 different names. So each time I write a select query as Sreeshad has mentioned. The first time I get the value. But in the second time when I assign the value to a new variable, I get null value. It simply seems like my temp table don't have a row corresponding to the name I mentioned second time. Is there a problem with what I'm doing?

Comment: @DivyaRose did you try to `select *` without filter to check what is there in your temp table?

Comment: Yes. I did. There were 4 rows. Until then everything seems to be good and fine. When the validation begins, it seems like there's only one row in the table.

Comment: I added another approach - you may try it. In code you have check `where` filters - may be you missed something. Or like Sreeshad attempting to filter with same `@id` value while there are actually different ids in each row.

Comment: I think that the second approach would probably work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have `RETURN` in your `IF` statment.

```
  ... RETURN 1000
  and 
  ... RETURN 1001
```

After insert a row the procedure end.

Maybe you want to assign a result to a variable

```
@return_Value = ''

    @return_Value = @return_Value + '1000, '             
 ....
    @return_Value = @return_Value + '1001, '

RETURN @return_Value
```

Comment: I need to exit from the SP if there is one single error. That's why i return from the if condition.